# Implementation of ALS in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I work now with `ALS` implemented in [Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark). In the directory `/org/apache/spark/` are two different packages [ml and mllib](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark). Each of both packages has the subfolder `recommendation` and in this folder the class `ALS.scala`  (mllib has additional also MatrixFactorizationModel.scala)

My question is, what is a difference between `ml` and `mllib` directories? 
For example I have found [the tutorial of using ALS](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html) of Apache Spark in the net. The package mllib is used in this tutorial. When I can use the package ml? Why we need to have two different packages ml and mllib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark ML Lib is being reworked now. Old classes are in mllib packages, new in ml. New classes are basing on DataFrames and could be faster due to Tungsten optimisation.

Generally you should use ml package if it is possible, as in the future mllib package will be deprecated and removed.

Edit: I don't have any link to full tutorial, but here is ALS code used by me:

```
val als = new ALS()
    .setUserCol("userCol")
    .setItemCol("itemCol")
    .setRank(rank)
    .setMaxIter(iterationNumber)
    .setRegParam(lambda)

val model = als.fit(trainingDataFrame)
val predictions = model.transform (dataFrameToPredict)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. So, the possible output of ALS from both packages should be similar (just, one is new, the other is outdated and ready to be removed)? And one question more, can someboddy get me a link for the tutoirial in the package ml? Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, output should be similar - as far as I know ALSModel in ml package uses old implementation currently ;) Please look into edit, I've added code snippet

Comment: Thank you very much for code sharing, I have googled a little bit, but found only examples in mllib. In your code the `trainingDataFormat` is an object created be the call of the method `train`?

Comment: trainingDataFrame is a DataFrame on which I'm training model - in old API there is a train() method, which needs a RDD as a parameter, in new it's called fit () and need DataFrame with user and item columns

Comment: if you're using pyspark it would be better to use ml package to get the same performance as when used using java or scala. ML package is implemented using dataframes while MLlib uses RDD. I would recommend you to read the material here https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html

Comment: @Bigby in question there is a "scala" tag ;) However thanks for comment, can be useful for other people

Comment: @Bigby, thank you, it is very useful. Currently I'm interested in Scala version.